# Shell Script to open SSH connection execute a command

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, expect

I`m having dificult in create an script, that get folder with subfolders inside, and open an ssh connection with other server, execute an axel command to download each file from the folder, and erase the folder and the files when the job is done.

As soon this server and folder is open on internet, I pretend to use the Axel to speed up the file download.

Anyone can help me?

Thanx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please describe **exactly** what you're having trouble with. This isn't a "write your code for you" service; instead, we're trying to build a database of tightly-focused questions with canonical answers; a question this broad could be broken down into numerous smaller questions, and chances are that many if not most of those questions are already asked and answered here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the script to connect to remote server using ssh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh $username@$host bash script_to_run_on_server "$directory_path"
sleep 2
expect "password:" {
    send "${$password}\r"
}
interact
```

In the above script, host,username,password,directory_path are variables which you can replace according to your values.

your logic to `'execute an axel command to download each file from the folder, and erase the folder and the files when the job is done'` show be written in `script_to_run_on_server`.

Note: Make sure, the directory have read,write excess from the server environment.

Comment: If you *must* encourage folks to pass a plaintext password around during programmatic use, why not suggest `sshpass` rather than reinventing the wheel with `expect`?

Comment: ...that said, I don't see anything in the question that requires plaintext passwords (vs, say, RSA keys) at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy- I wasn't aware of sshpass. I will go through it's man page